# How to trigger all onChange events of all TMemo components in a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I want to trigger all onChange events of all TMemo components in a form, when the form is shown.

For this i'm using the code below :

```
var
  i: integer;
  m: tmemo;
begin
  for i := 0 to componentcount - 1 do
  begin
    if components[i] is tmemo then
    begin
      m := components[i] as tmemo;
      m.onchange(m);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Problem is, i'm getting some Access Violations on the loop above, probably due the fact some memos don't have an onChange event.

How can i test if the event exists, before trigger it on the line below ?

```
m.onchange(m);
```

Comment: Tried if (m.onchange <> nil) , but i'm getting E2035 Not enough actual parameters

Comment: Sorry, check `if Assigned(m.OnChange)`

Comment: Worked, thanks ! Please submit an answer, i'll accept

Comment: Thanks, maybe I do, but may I first ask you why you want to trigger the event handlers even if not any change is made to corresponding memo? I'm just curious.

Comment: Actually i have a procedure on my form where it saves all settings and values of components and when it opens later, another procedure load all settings again. So that's why i need to trigger onChange on all memos, because each memo has a onChange event.

Comment: "_because each memo has a onChange event_" - well, obviously not.

Comment: You should consider another way of doing that stuff. You can use your Component loop to save the Text of your memo dircetly to a File without using th onChange Event between. If you use this solution every memo that will be added later, is also saved and you do not have to care about that any more.

Comment: @delphirules "*when it opens later, another procedure load all settings again*" - why not simply have the loading code call the `OnChange` event of each component it loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if an event handler is assigned before calling it :

```pascal
if Assigned(m.OnChange) then
  m.OnChange(m);
```